# How can I find a replacement screw/bolt?

Tags: screws

I have a cast iron Christmas tree stand and I need to replace the screws/bolts. Where can I get them and/or how can I determine the thread so that I can check at a hardware store?

Comment: Your question is way to general to answer. Why not just take the stand to the hardware store and ask a clerk to help you find the right replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Most hardware stores have thread to test if there the right thread. 
So your better of taking the stand or bolts  to the hardware and test it on the threads
When you find the right thread the packets are marked with the size an thread of tho bolt. 
If you can't find the right thread ask a worker there to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need the flat end pieces that go against the tree for the stand to be safe.  I have bolts but they wouldn't work just screwing the bolts against or even into the tree.  They need more surface area.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.